# com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: File with name internal.pcl does not exist in storage metadata

Tags: docker, orientdb

Run the orientdb with the docker. The server is powered off, restart the server, and then start orientdb fails, the error is shown below，but can I find the file in the folder 'metadata'?

```
2020-04-05 11:37:39:282 INFO  Detected limit of amount of simultaneously open files is 1048576,  limit of open files for disk cache will be set to 523776 [ONative]
2020-04-05 11:37:39:298 INFO  Loading configuration from: /orientdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2020-04-05 11:37:39:587 INFO  OrientDB Server v3.0.22 - Veloce (build 8afc634a2ea9c351898ae57dee8d739ff4851252, branch 3.0.x) is starting up... [OServer]
2020-04-05 11:37:39:619 INFO  OrientDB config DISKCACHE=800MB [orientechnologies]
2020-04-05 11:37:39:697 INFO  System is started under an effective user : `root` [OEngineLocalPaginated]
2020-04-05 11:37:39:697 INFO  Allocation of 12160 pages. [OEngineLocalPaginated]
2020-04-05 11:37:39:880 INFO  WAL maximum segment size is set to 32,241 MB [OrientDBDistributed]
2020-04-05 11:37:39:882 INFO  Databases directory: /orientdb/databases [OServer]
2020-04-05 11:37:39:987 INFO  Direct IO for WAL located in /orientdb/databases/OSystem is allowed with block size 4096 bytes. [OCASDiskWriteAheadLog]
2020-04-05 11:37:39:988 INFO  Page size for WAL located in /orientdb/databases/OSystem is set to 4096 bytes. [OCASDiskWriteAheadLog]
2020-04-05 11:37:40:587 INFO  Storage 'plocal:/orientdb/databases/OSystem' is opened under OrientDB distribution : 3.0.22 - Veloce (build 8afc634a2ea9c351898ae57dee8d739ff4851252, branch 3.0.x) [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:013 INFO  Listening binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 (protocol v.37, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:019 INFO  Listening http connections on 0.0.0.0:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:024 INFO  Found ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD variable, using this value as root's password [OServer]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:764 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin 'orientdb-studio-3.0.22.zip'... [OServerPluginManager]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:767 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin 'orientdb-etl-3.0.22.jar'... [OServerPluginManager]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:773 INFO  ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator is active [ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:776 INFO  OServerConfigAuthenticator is active [OServerConfigAuthenticator]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:777 INFO  OSystemUserAuthenticator is active [OSystemUserAuthenticator]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:778 INFO  [OVariableParser.resolveVariables] Property not found: distributed [orientechnologies]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:785 WARNI Authenticated clients can execute any kind of code into the server by using the following allowed languages: [sql] [OServerSideScriptInterpreter]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:788 INFO  OrientDB Studio available at http://172.18.0.2:2480/studio/index.html [OServer]
2020-04-05 11:37:41:788 INFO  OrientDB Server is active v3.0.22 - Veloce (build 8afc634a2ea9c351898ae57dee8d739ff4851252, branch 3.0.x). [OServer]
2020-04-05 11:38:16:755 INFO  Direct IO for WAL located in /orientdb/databases/metadata is allowed with block size 4096 bytes. [OCASDiskWriteAheadLog]
2020-04-05 11:38:16:755 INFO  Page size for WAL located in /orientdb/databases/metadata is set to 4096 bytes. [OCASDiskWriteAheadLog]Exception `6EA2C93F` in storage `plocal:/orientdb/databases/metadata`: 3.0.22 - Veloce (build 8afc634a2ea9c351898ae57dee8d739ff4851252, branch 3.0.x)
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: File with name internal.pcl does not exist in storage metadata
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.OWOWCache.loadFile(OWOWCache.java:732)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.base.ODurableComponent.openFile(ODurableComponent.java:188)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cluster.v0.OPaginatedClusterV0.open(OPaginatedClusterV0.java:192)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.openClusters(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:532)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.open(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:391)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBEmbedded.openNoAuthenticate(OrientDBEmbedded.java:236)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBEmbedded.openNoAuthenticate(OrientDBEmbedded.java:59)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.openDatabase(OServer.java:936)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.openDatabase(OServer.java:908)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.authenticate(OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.java:162)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.beforeExecute(OServerCommandAuthenticatedDbAbstract.java:122)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.get.OServerCommandGetConnect.beforeExecute(OServerCommandGetConnect.java:50)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.service(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:225)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.execute(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:707)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:69)
```